# OpenCV Rectangle are black when image is saved as bitmap

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.1

Following is the image seen on mobile screen before saving :

[image]

After saving the image to external storage :

[image]

Please guide how to fix the color of the rectangles drawn by the opencv.

Below is my code :

```
  Bitmap new_bitmap = takeScreenShot(findViewById(R.id.img));
  Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(new_bitmap);
  Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
  File outFile = new File("External directory", "My folder name");
  FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
  mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
  outStream.flush();
  outStream.close();

  public Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap image = view.getDrawingCache();

    if (image != null) {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Following code to set the image:

```
  Bitmap resultBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Path for image");
  Mat m_ogr = new Mat(resultBitmap.getWidth(), resultBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
  List<Rect> rectList = "Some list with Rect elements";
  for (int fi = 0; fi < rectList.size(); fi++) {
    Imgproc.rectangle(m_ogr, new Point(rectList.get(fi).x, rectList.get(fi).y), 
    new Point(rectList.get(fi).x + rectList.get(fi).width, rectList.get(fi).y + rectList.get(fi).height), 
    new Scalar(50, 205, 50), 2);
   }
  Utils.matToBitmap(m_ogr, resultBitmap);
  img.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you display the image before saving? OpenCV does not use the alpha channel, maybe it is 0 at rectangle positions (e.g. if you draw the rectangle with only 3 color values instead of 4)?

Comment: I have updated my question with necessary code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

After @Micka pointed out about alpha channel,

I fixed this issue by doing following things:

```
 //First Change
 Mat m_ogr = new Mat(resultBitmap.getWidth(), resultBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

 //Second Change
 Imgproc.rectangle(m_ogr, new Point(rectList.get(fi).x, rectList.get(fi).y), 
new Point(rectList.get(fi).x + rectList.get(fi).width, rectList.get(fi).y + rectList.get(fi).height), 
new Scalar(50, 205, 50, 255), 2);
```

Now the color is correct. Thanks.